# OpenMP in FORTRAN does not run expected number of threads

Tags: parallel-processing, cygwin, fortran, openmp

I am new to parallel programming, and am having trouble getting a simple parallel Fortran program to use multiple threads in OpenMP.  The following program:

```
   Program Hello
   Use omp_lib
   Implicit None

   INTEGER        nthreads
   nthreads = 4

   CALL OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS(nthreads)

   write(*,*) omp_get_num_procs()
   write(*,*) omp_get_max_threads()
   write(*,*) omp_get_num_threads()

   !$OMP PARALLEL
     Write(*,*) 'Hello'
     Write(*,*) omp_get_num_threads()
   !%OMP END PARALLEL

   End Program Hello
```

Produces the result:

```
      32
       4
       1
   Hello
       1
```

What is the reason that the number of threads inside the parallel region is not the same as nthreads that I set above?  I am compiling the program using gfortran -f openmp Hello.f on a Windows machine running cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

I try it compiling in Linux with gfortran. And I get error because the OMP directives. I changed it to:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL
Write(*,*) 'Hello'
Write(*,*) omp_get_num_threads()
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

(Notice `!$OMP`). And now it works. The output:

```
$ ./a.out 
      16
       4
       1
Hello
       4
Hello
       4
Hello
       4
Hello
       4
```

Answer (score 0):

The sentinel, i.e. `!$omp` or `*$omp` or `c$omp` **must** appear at the beginning of the line by itself. 
It simply launches a single thread otherwise and doesn't complain.

```
!$OMP PARALLEL
      Write(*,*) 'Hello'
      Write(*,*) omp_get_num_threads()
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

Comment: Not true for !$OMP which does not need to start at the column 1

Comment: @FrancoisJacq Do you mean the uppercase variant? I encountered this issue when I was trying to run it. It throws no errors, but it also runs on a single thread.

Comment: No : uppercase and lowercase are equivalent in Fortran. I just mention that ! is the symbol of the bang comment : it may be put at any column in a Fortran instruction : al the rest of the line is assumed to be a comment. In the framework of OpenMP, all OMP declarations are standard Fortran comment lines which therefore follow the rules of these comments : in fixed form, such comment line begins by a 'c' or '*' in the first column or a '!' in any column... In free form, only the last possibility exists. The mistake of the OP was just !%OMP instead of !$OMP : nothing to do with the location of !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the issue or not, but the last directive in the OP's code has a % instead of a $. May be just a typo, but I had recently posted code that a silly typo like that caused me trouble.

Comment: Oh! Francois Jacq, said it in a comment... he should get the credit